# If Nelson Algren not present in the scene then why Mank mentioned his name here?

Tags: plot-explanation, mank

In *Mank* (2020), Orson Welles scolds alcoholic writer Mank, who wants screen credits, and that is
against the contract:

> Orson Welles: Remind me never again to work with a washed-up
> alcoholic!
>
> Mank: Duly noted. **Nelson Algren**, please copy.

If Nelson Algren not present in the scene then why Mank mentioned his name here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Nelson Algren](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelson_Algren) had some bad habits like gambling and drinking, and like many of his characters, mainly "*bad boys*" even though they were not pictured like this.

Mank and Algren shared many similarities. In this case, Mank and Welles are in the same kind of situation, a writer, a drinker, a film maker, and Mank references to this writer and background/story.

> Mankiewicz was often asked to fix other writers' screenplays, with much of his work uncredited. [source](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herman_J._Mankiewicz)